# Rake Environment Superclass Mismatch then including lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, resque

I have many controllers that are identically named in [different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162628/same-controller-name-in-two-different-directories):

```
Marketplace::ProductsController < ApplicationController

Office::Marketplace::ProductsController < Office::BaseController

API::V2::Marketplace::ProductsController < BaseController
```

which are working fine with `rails s` and `rails c`, both unit tests and cucumber tests.

However, as I followed [getting started with ActiveJob tutorial](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job), and tried to run the command `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work` it produces the following error.

```
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class ProductsController
```

It seems as if resque isn't happy about these two identically named controllers — namespaced they may be — inheriting from different classes. Is there any reason why `rake environment` is complaining every other rake task and rails is fine with it.

**Update 1:**

I have found that for `API::V2::Marketplace::ProductsController` is defined as below:

```
module API
  module V2
    class Marketplace::ProductsController < BaseController
    end
  end
end
```

Once I changed it to below, the error seems to have been solved.

```
class API::V2::Marketplace::ProductsController < API::V2:BaseController
end
```

Meanwhile `Marketplace::ShopsController` and `API::V2::Marketplace::ShopsController` has no problem, even though the latter was defined as below

```
module API
  module V2
    class Marketplace::ShopsController < BaseController
  end
end
```

The error is now about some rspec files in my `lib` folder. I have added some lib folder that are slightly related to the code base, but not really used. Apparently, it's trying to load these files and giving me error such as this when the `QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work` command was issued.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `describe' for main:Object
```

Once I removed those legacy files out of lib folders, I get no error.

Does `rake environment` include everything from lib? I'm finding this incredulous since all other rake tasks that I have been running do nothing like that.

Update 2:

While closer inspection with `--trace`. I could see my `puts` message like this.

```
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
** My puts message.**
** Invoke resque:setup
** Execute resque:work
```

`resque:preload` seems like the culprit. Is there anyway I could fix that from greedily including everything?

Answer (score 0):

While these two might seem identical the actual lookup of `BaseController` is quite different:

```
class API::V2::Marketplace::ProductsController < BaseController; end

module API
  module V2
    module Marketplace
      # will use this class as super
      class BaseController; end

      class ProductsController < BaseController; end
    end
  end
end
```

In the first example `BaseController` will be resolved from the "global" namespace (the `main` object). While in the second it will be resolved from the current nesting.

So if you define a class like in the first example you should explicitly state the full path to the superclass.

The error with the missplaced RSpec specs is likely that they relied on the behavior of older versions of RSpec where it placed its DSL in the main object or the fact that the RSpec gem might not even be loaded in the current environment.

Rails by default does not require each file in `lib` - instead I suspect the culprit is a faulty attempt at autoloading the files.

Comment: I've added another update, which found `resque:preload` as the culprit. Any way to stop it from greedily loading everything?